# Using QUERY to filter multiple criteria from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a column with 3 options:

```
Primary
Secondary
[empty cell]
```

I am currently using this formula to filter all rows that contain "Primary" from one spreadsheet to another and it's working well.

```
=query(importrange("https://URL", "CAT!A1:R"), "select * where Col2 = 'Primary'")
```

I now need to filter rows that are also empty. I can't seem to figure out how to add the second criteria.

*Or*, what may make more sense, I need to filter for everything *but* "Secondary".

Comment: Generally speaking, `!=` or `<>` are usually used for "not equals". Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

OP presumably did try what was recommended in a Comment, found that satisfactory,  and never bothered to report back. For the sake of an answer:

```
=query(importrange(" k e y ","CAT!A:R"),"select * where Col2 <> 'Secondary'")
```

`k e y` need not be the entire URL. Just the part that looks like this is sufficient:

```
1MiNSa3xN5sjAo43zt-oU4gzjaRfYwFQ-lbGWkZi5z64
```

No need to specify the first row of the source when whole columns are involved.
Since acquired with IMPORTRANGE columns can't be referenced by just letters (ie must be `Col2` (case sensitive) rather than `B`).
The exclusion term (`Secondary`) is case sensitive.

Since acquiring all rows blank in ColumnB of the source it may be a good idea to add further provision, such as specifying a sort order, to avoid all (if any) empty rows rising to the top.